# Abstraction vs Encapsulation

Tags: oop

Is it correct to say that
Abstraction is achieved by abstract classes and abstract classes are just a blueprint of the classes which inherit the abstract class. So abstraction is not basically just hiding information, but it is a design requirement that defines how inherited classes or their functions should be implemented. Where as in encapsulation as the term refers is encapsulating all the data in a single class and protecting the data with access modifiers.
So why is abstraction referred to information hiding when the concept itself is derived from 'abstract' which means concept, idea or infrastructure in terms of software

Explaining abstraction and encapsulation.
I am expecting the difference between them.

Comment: Encapsulation is a means of abstraction. Abstraction is a means of simplification. Abstraction isn't as much of a "design requirement" for its own sake but often as a response to growing complexity within a system.

Answer (score 0):

Like so many other concepts in software development (*service*, *unit test*, *component*, etc.) the words *abstraction* and *encapsulation* are nebulous; there's no *authoritative* definition of these terms.

I base my own interpretation of these terms on [Object-Oriented Software Construction](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/oosc) by Bertrand Meyer and [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/appp) by Robert C. Martin.

According to Robert C. Martin,

> "Abstraction is the elimination of the irrelevant and the amplification of the essential"

One should be careful not to confuse this notion with a specific language keyword such as `abstract`. It's not the same. You can have 'normal' classes and objects that perfectly eliminate the irrelevant and amplify the essential, and you can have `abstract` classes the amplify the irrelevant and eliminate the essential.

Or, as Dijkstra phrased it in his 1972 Turing lecture *The Humble Programmer:*

> "The purpose of abstraction is *not* to be vague, but to create a new semantic level in which one can be absolutely precise"

The same goes for the word *encapsulation*. The earliest I've run into this idea may be in Meyer's book, in which he discusses *contracts*. The idea here is that a contract describes how a client can and should interact with an object without knowing anything about its implementation details.

This, too, is a much more foundational concept than object-oriented programming; it [also applies to functional programming](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/10/24/encapsulation-in-functional-programming).

While *encapsulation* as a concept may be as 'late' as the mid-eighties, I consider the idea related to Parnas' 1972 paper on *information hiding*. I don't know if Meyer was inspired by that or not, but I'd be surprised if he didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to figure it out with an example. You have `interface Book` with methods `title`, `content`, etc. and classes `FileSystemBook` (getting a filesystem path in a constructor), `DbBook` (getting sql connection in a constructor), etc. that implement the `interface Book`.

Defining the interface is an `abstraction` (define something general for all implementations).

Getting and hiding necessary objects for implementations (filesystem path, sql connection, etc.) is `encapsulation`.

You are hiding implementation using `encapsulation` behind an `abstraction`.

Answer (score 0):

You are partially correct though.

Let me try to give you a simplified one-line key difference.

> **Abstraction**:
>
> Provides a high-level view, focusing on what an object does rather
> than how it does it.
>
> **Encapsulation**:
>
> Protects the internal details of objects and controls how they are
> accessed or modified.

Ok let me give you a simple example.

***Making a call on your phone:***

*Abstraction*: You simply tap a contact and initiate a call. You don't need to understand the cellular network protocols or signal routing.

The phone abstracts the complexity of the call process for a user-friendly experience.

*Encapsulation*: Your phone's operating system encapsulates the call functionality.

The internal components (microphone, speaker, network connection) and the code that manages them are hidden.

> Abstraction is a design principle, while encapsulation is an
> implementation technique.

Hope this helps to understand its differences.